# Cancel asynctask launched with onClickListener in an Adapter created inside onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This is my context: I have an activity which downloads a list of video and set them into an adapter. When user clicks on each item, application downloads and streams video in an external application.
So, let's see some code. Main activity has this:

```
new TvAsyncTask(getActivity(), gridView, progressBar).execute();
```

TvAsyncTask download video list and sets it like here:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<VideoPreviewData> list) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        final TvListAdapter adapter = new TvListAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_video_list, list);

        videoGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
                  String videoUrl = adapter.getItem(position).getLink();
                  //Launch asyncTask to download video an load it into an external media player
                  new GetVideoAsyncTask(activity).execute(videoUrl);                  
              }
            });
        if (videoGridView!=null) videoGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

GetVideoAsyncTask load video link and lauch an Intent in an external application to stream that video. In order to do this, during onLoading I set a ProgressDialog that shows to the user a loading message. After that loading is completed, intent is launched.

**Problem**
When ProgressDialog is shown and user click "back button" the dialog is cancelled but the asynctask continues to work. So when it finishes it launches intent.
I want to prevent this. I have a onPause method in MainActivity, but I don't have a reference of GetVideoAsyncTask launched from adapter. So I cannot call method AsyncTask.cancel(true) in order to deny intent launch. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: I try this compromise: SetCancelable(false) on ProgressDialog. In this way user has no possibility to cancel that action and so I don't need to stop asyncTask.
It's not the best idea, because network can be slow and user maybe don't want to wait.. But no others solution found.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of your async task class;

```
TvAsyncTask tvTask = new TvAsyncTask(getActivity(), gridView, progressBar);
tvTask.execute();
```

Then in the TvAsyncTask class override the onCanceled function

```
@Override
        protected void onCancelled() 
        {
super.onCancelled();
}
```

In your back button code check:

```
if(tvTask != null)
tvTask.cancel(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

in main activity you can keep a reference to `GetVideoAsyncTask` and `TvAsyncTask` and in onPause cancel both of them.

inActivity:

```
GetVideoAsyncTask getVideoAsyncTask;
TvAsyncTask tvAsyncTask;
```

in onCreate:

```
tvAsyncTask=new TvAsyncTask(getActivity(), gridView, progressBar);
tvAsyncTask.execute();
```

and in onItemClick

```
getVideoAsyncTask=new GetVideoAsyncTask(activity); 
getVideoAsyncTask.execute(videoUrl);
```

in onPause:

```
if(tvAsyncTask!=null&&!tvAsyncTask.isCancelled())
tvAsyncTask.cancel(true);
if(getVideoAsyncTask!=null&&!getVideoAsyncTask.isCancelled())
getVideoAsyncTask.cancel(true);
```

Comment: My problem is that getVideoAsyncTask is an object created inside onClickListener inside TvAsyncTask. I cannot set it from onItemClick(). I have no reference to it..